# How to Patch a test result on Azure Devops through the API

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-devops, axios

I'm trying to update the results for a testcase on Azure Devops through the API using axios, but at the end of my request I get this error

```
Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: results
```

And this is my request

```
axios({
        method: 'patch',
        url: resultUrl,
        data: {
            "outcome": "Failed",
        },
        auth: {
            username: config.credentials.username,
            password: config.credentials.password
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        } 
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample request body for updating a test case result set:

```
[
  {
    "id": 100000,
    "state": "Completed",
    "outcome" : "Failed,
    "comment": "Website theme is looking good",
    "associatedBugs": [
      {
        "id": 30
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 100001,
    "state": "Completed",
    "outcome" : "Failed,
    "comment": "Website links are failing because of incorrect container id",
    "failureType": "Known Issue"
  }
]
```

and here is the Patch Url for the same:

PATCH https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC/_apis/test/Runs/26/results?api-version=5.0

Can you try updating the request data body in your api call and try.

Hope it helps. **MV**